# why is the foreach argument invalid this time, and valid the previus time

Tags: php, select, foreach

I have a select and which then creates a list.  I am using the same arguments style for both, but one is valid, the other is not.  I am confused as to why one is valid and the other not.
The select works, the next call doesn't

```
 $dogh='select * from topics order by topic;';

  echo '<select name = "cards"  >';

  $RU= $QQQ->query($dogh);
  foreach ($RU as $roe)
  {
  echo '<option value =' .$roe['topic']." > ".$roe['topic']."</option>";
  }
 echo '</select>';
if    (isset($_POST['cards']))  $writer_id=$_POST['cards'];
$kat='select * from neatly where topics =   '.$roe['topic'];
   $RT= $QQQ->query($kat);
foreach($RT as $roe)
{
```

Comment: `$row['topic']` will need to be enclosed in single quotes if it's not numeric. Try this: `$kat="select * from neatly where topics =   '{$roe['topic']}'";`

Comment: did not help anything.  I am mystified

Comment: In the second query it should be `topic = `, not `topics = `